# How to get the name of a column at a specific index and print it into another column using python and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, indexing

I'm a python newbie and need help with a specfic task. My main goal is to identify all indicies with their specific values and column-names which are greater than 0 within a row and to sum up these values below each other into another column within the same row.

Here is what I tried:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
table = {
    'A':[0, 2, 0, 5],
    'B' :[4, 1, 3, 0],
    'C':[2, 9, 0, 6],
    'D':[1, 0, 1, 6]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
print(df)

# create a new column that sums up the row
df['summary'] = 'NoData'

# print the header
print(df.columns.values)

   A  B  C  D summary
0  0  4  2  1  NoData
1  2  1  9  0  NoData
2  0  3  0  1  NoData
3  5  0  6  6  NoData

# get length of rows and columns
row = len(df.index)
column = len(df.columns)

# If a value at a spefic index is greater
# than 0, take the column name and the value at that index and print it into the column
#'summary'. Also write all values greater than 0 within a row below each other

for i in range(row):
    for j in range(column):
        if df.iloc[i][j] > 0:
            df.at[i,'summary'] = df.columns(df.iloc[i][j]) + '\n'
```

I hope it is a bit clear what I want to achieve. Here is a picture of how the result should look in the column 'summary'

[image]

Comment: Yes, exactly! Do you have any idea how to do that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need a `for loop`.

Starting with `df`:

```
    A   B   C   D
0   0   4   2   1
1   2   1   9   0
2   0   3   0   1
3   5   0   6   6
```

You can do:

```
# Define an helper function
def f(val, col_name):
    # You can modify this function in order to customize the summary string
    return "" if val == 0 else str(val) + col_name + "\n"

# Assign summary column
df["summary"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(f, args=(x.name,))).sum(axis=1).str[:-1]
```

Output:

```
   A    B   C   D   summary
0   0   4   2   1   4B\n2C\n1D
1   2   1   9   0   2A\n1B\n9C
2   0   3   0   1   3B\n1D
3   5   0   6   6   5A\n6C\n6D
```

It works for longer column names as well:

```
      one  two  three four summary
0     0    4    2     1    4two\n2three\n1four
1     2    1    9     0    2one\n1two\n9three
2     0    3    0     1    3two\n1four
3     5    0    6     6    5one\n6three\n6four
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked with the example table. But my actual table has other column names than just 'A', 'B' etc. but names with more strings like 'student' or 'grade'. Every time I try that code on my table I always get the Error: TypeError: func() takes 2 positional arguments but 8 were given. Do you know how I can fix that problem?

Comment: @Radde1683 Try to add a comma after `x.name`, so that it becomes: `df["summary"] = df.apply(lambda x: x.apply(func, args=(x.name,))).sum(axis=1).str[:-1]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
table = {
    'A':[0, 2, 0, 5],
    'B' :[4, 1, 3, 0],
    'C':[2, 9, 0, 6],
    'D':[1, 0, 1, 6]
              }
df = pd.DataFrame(table)
print(df)

print(f'\n\n-------------BREAK-----------\n\n')
def func(line):
    templist = ''
    list_col = line.index.values.tolist()
    temp = line.values.tolist()
    for x in  range(0, len(temp)):
        if (temp[x] <= 0):
            pass
        else:
            if (x == 0 ):
                templist = f"{temp[x]}{list_col[x]}"
            else:
                templist = f"{templist}\n{temp[x]}{list_col[x]}"
    return templist
        

df['summary'] = df.apply(func, axis = 1)
print(df)
```

EXIT

```py
   A  B  C  D
0  0  4  2  1
1  2  1  9  0
2  0  3  0  1
3  5  0  6  6


-------------BREAK-----------

   A  B  C  D       summary
0  0  4  2  1  \n4B\n2C\n1D
1  2  1  9  0    2A\n1B\n9C
2  0  3  0  1      \n3B\n1D
3  5  0  6  6    5A\n6C\n6D
```

Comment: Hey, thank you really much for your answer! But unfortunately I always get the error 'invalid syntax'. I think it has something to do with the 'f' in front of the quotation marks. What does the 'f' do?

Comment: it's just to format a string so that I can put a variable inside

Comment: Did you get an error when you ran this exact code? Can you post in the comments what the error is?

Comment: Hey, the error is just: SyntaxError: invalid syntax. I think it has something to with my python version. I'm using 2.7, but the f-string only works after version 3.6.

Comment: try replacing ```f"{temp[x]}{list_col[x]}" ```  with ```str(temp[x]) + str(list_col[x])" ```  and  ```f"{templist}\n{temp[x]}{list_col[x]}"```  by  ```str(templist)+"\n"+str(temp[x]) + str(list_col[ x])```